# High memory usage when creating websocket connections via websockets.connect() in python

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I am using use [this](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) library (websockets-7.0) to create 2000 connections to connect to a websocket server in python 3.6. Memory is increasing dramatically. Here is my code:

```
import asyncio,websockets

async def test2(i):                                        
    await websockets.connect( "wss://echo.websocket.org")

async def test():                                          
    await asyncio.gather(*(test2(i) for i in range(2000) ))

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(test())
```

It takes over 3GB memory. It's so weird. Does it make sense? BTW, I found that if I change wss to ws, the memory usage is normal. It might be something wrong with TLS.

Comment: I am also experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some memory issues in the websockets library. I change the library to aiohttp and it works fine.